# What is the benefit to reannealing during Simulated Annealing?

Tags: simulated-annealing

I'm reading up on different ways to implement the Simulated Annealing algorithm. MathWorks's [implementation for MatLab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/simulated-annealing-options.html#bq26j8s-6) was the first time I had come across the concept of *reannealing* during simulated annealing. As I understand it based on that documentation, the simulation runs a number of times until *ReannealInterval* number of new values have been selected, at which point it triggers another function that determines a new initial temperature (higher than the current temperature) and then restarts the simulation using the new temperature and the current value. The reannealing loop continues until some criteria other than `temperature <= 0` is met. I know that the current temperature plays a role in the probability of accepting a worse solution, but what is the benefit to doing this multiple times as opposed to configuring the initial simulation to run longer with a more slowly decaying temperature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a higher temperature, it's easier to make jumps into regions with significantly poorer solutions.  This can help you get out of local minima which are "deep" - you can do it in one or two steps, instead of having to chain together several smaller steps, which relies, writing intuitively, on the proposals being arranged just right as well as more luck required with the sequence of acceptance random number generators (due to having to make several acceptance "rolls" instead of just one or two.)

Reannealing allows the reset of the temperature to a higher level than it would be if you simply slowed down the decay.  Of course, there's little point if you're simply upping the temperature by a few percentage points when performing the reannealing!  But the faster decay rate + reannealing means you tend to get stuck in certain types of local minima less often, and you still have a reasonably good overall convergence rate.

There is no silver bullet, however, and reannealing is neither a dominant nor a dominated strategy.  Your mileage may vary!